# Using multiple string arrays in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a very simple problem but I can't solve it. I want to shred the data from the service and throw it into the array, but I can't make it what I want, neither using property nor array.

Example Text: `abc~sdfgsdg|def~dgdfgdf|cvx~fgdfgfdh|`

Example Code:

```
let exampleText: string = 'abc~sdfgsdg|def~dgdfgdf|cvx~fgdfgfdh|'
let test: [string, string][];
let test2 = exampleTest.split('|');
test2.forEach(element => {
          let test3 = element.split('~'); 
          let t6 = test3[0]
          let t8 = test3[1]
          test.push(t6,t8)
        });
```

Error: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, string]'.ts(2345)`

Another way:

```
let exampleText: string = 'abc~sdfgsdg|def~dgdfgdf|cvx~fgdfgfdh|'
let test: [Pro1:string,Pro2:string];
let test2 = exampleTest.split('|');
test2.forEach(element => {
          let test3 = element.split('~'); 
          let t6 = test3[0]
          let t8 = test3[1]
          test.push(t6,t8)
        });
```

Error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`

The result I want:

```
console.log(test[0][0]) //print 'abc'
console.log(test[0][1]) //print 'sdfgsdg'
console.log(test[1][0]) //print 'def'
console.log(test[1][1]) //print 'dgdfgdf'
```

Or

```
console.log(test[0].Pro1) //print 'abc'
console.log(test[0].Pro2) //print 'sdfgsdg'
console.log(test[1].Pro1) //print 'def'
console.log(test[1].Pro2) //print 'dgdfgdf'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to initialize the `test` array. Otherwise, you can't push into it.

```
let test: [string, string][] = [];
```

`test` contains `string` tuples of size 2. Pushing a `string` into it won't work. You need to construct a tuple consisting of `t6` and `t8` and push it.

```
test2.forEach((element) => {
  let test3 = element.split("~");
  let t6 = test3[0];
  let t8 = test3[1];
  test.push([t6, t8]);
});
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBCAeCGC2AHUAVGYBcEDOYBOAlgHYDmEAvBAESwBGAxgH7YAmAZiayQD4shuMWJdsLbd6AN2iMOItiwAW3KgG4AUKEhgQuLAG1chUgBoc+YiQC6eyxQg31miNtwAmOzATIQaaGAB02MgEYAAUVMoAlOpqLmCu-mwA9ngAorD0CqGhIKDwIERgkRQAfBAA3moQEE5xAMweeQUBQcAh4YxU0VU14M4AbHb1egAMlurVtQAcQzpgdXoAjOM9cf6IAK7YWXpg-aZgU5bdAL7davRJRNhJoP7ASSShcd1AA)

Comment: Oh finally. I've been trying for 2 hours on this little thing. Thank you so much.